# Laravel 8 sort and paginate search results

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, pagination

```
$query = $request->get('query');
        
    if($query) {
        //$resources = Resource::search($query)->get()->load('featuredImage', 'type', 'tags');
        $resources = Resource::search($query)->orderBy('publish_date','asc')->paginate(5)->setPath('')->appends(request()->input());
        $resources->load('featuredImage', 'type', 'tags');
    }
```

So I have a search results page in Laravel 8 that is almost working as expected. The above works but instead of the whole query ordered by only the items per page are ordered e.g. only items on page 1 of results are ordered by published date.

I'm not sure how the pagination is happening first.